# Splitting the cells in a table

Tags: tables

Given the codes,
\begin{tabular}{@{}11@{}}

what do the codes @{} and 11@{} within the command mean or imply?

Comment: I guess the real code for the tabular preamble is `{@{}ll@{}}` (the letter l, not the digit 1). It means we have two left-aligned columns, and that the left column has no horizontal padding on the left, and the right column  no horizontal padding on the right.

Comment: See introductory text about tables: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables

Comment: Hello there! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly Overleaf-related. I hope you manage to solve the issue!